# Xamarin grid, column and row amounts

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi im relatively new to c# code and i was wondering if there is any way to get the amount of columns and rows in a grid and store that amount in a variable

Something like:
`var columnamount = grid.columnamount;`

But i could not find anything that works

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get a count of the columns and rows directly via the ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions properties. No need to enumerate the children of the grid because you may not have views in every column/row.

```
var columnCount = grid.ColumnDefintions.Count;
var rowCount = grid.RowDefinitions.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/).

You might be able to do it this way, purely based on what I see in the docs:

```
var countColumns = grid.Children.Where( c => c.Column).Max();
var countRows = grid.Children.Where( c => c.Row).Max();
```

But I'm not sure if you can access `Row` anf `Column` properties on the child element.

Comment: Thank you will be sure to check it out

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to check, I guess, but it's working (same thing for columns):

**EDIT:** nope, for columns it doesn't work

```cs
int GetRowsCount(Grid grid)
{
    var item = grid.Children.FirstOrDefault();
    return item != null ? Grid.GetRow(item) + 1 : 0;
}
```